# Picture tag uses wrong source on Chrome on Android

Tags: android, css, html, google-chrome, responsive-design

I am using the html5 picture tag to load the appropriate image:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="/path/to/image-450x450.jpg" media="(min-width:768px)">
    <source srcset="/path/to/image-600x600.jpg" media="(min-width:600px)">
    <source srcset="/path/to/image-450x450.jpg" media="(min-width:450px)">
    <img src="/path/to/image-224x224.jpg" alt="Alt text here">
</picture>
```

On my pc this loads up the first `source` image. On my tablet it is loading the second `source` image THEN the first `source` image.

I have plugged my tablet into my pc in developer mode so that I can inspect the elements and view the network tab from my pc.

That is how I learned that the tablet was loading the large images first, THEN the correct image.

I have read that browsers will apply the `source` of the first matching `media` attribute.

Frustratingly, I have `picture` elements on other pages and they are loading the images correctly, so why is this one doing it differently? How do I fix it?

I have changed the media query to different values but the browser seems to ignore it on first pass.

I have disabled javascript in case a plugin was to blame.

I thought maybe the browser was pre-fetching the 2nd image because the screen height was under 600px so I did an alert of `$(window).width()` and it is 800px so that isn't the answer either.

I am using Chrome 45.0.2454.94 on a Galaxy Tab 2 running android 4.2.2.

I can only assume other browsers/devices are having similar issues but I lack the ability to test on those devices. I am hoping if I fix the issue on this browser/device then it "should" be fixed on the other browsers/devices as well...

How do I get chrome on android to load the correct picture element?

[edit]

I have also implemented [PictureFill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) to see if that helped. It did not.

Comment: Editorial suggestion: you might add the `responsive-design` tag. (We really ought to have some specific `picture-element` or `responsive-images` tag at SO but I guess short of that  `responsive-design` is what people have been using.)

Comment: You have 450x450 twice; I assume the first one is intended to be bigger?

Comment: Do you use a `<meta name=viewport>` and if so, what does it say?

Comment: My viewport tag is: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. The picture dimensions are correct as the layout changes between browser widths.

Comment: If the window width is 800px, all three media queries are true. How about adding `and (max-width:...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have bumped into a [browser bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=526630) (sorry about that :/). It should be fixed in Chrome 46, currently in the beta channel.

Can you please test with Chrome Beta and verify that it in fact fixes that issue for you?

Comment: This does not appear to be an issue in the Chrome beta 46.